# Geometrical Calculus - Mini-Max Problem

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives

Two vehicles are heading for a crossroad (point C) and intend to pass straight through.

Vehicle A is $100$ km due North travelling at $80$ km/hr towards C Vehicle B is $150$ km due East travelling at $90$ km/hr towards C

Distance (D) between them in Time (t) is given by:

$D^2=100(145t^2−430t+325)$

Determine the time that it takes to minimise the distance between them.

Comment: I've tried everything that I thought possible!
I know that I definitely have to make y'=0, but I cannot find y' in a simple enough form to find what x values will make it = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Distance is minimum when $145t^2-430t$ is minimum. i.e. when $\frac{d(145t^2-430t)}{dt}=0$

So, $t=430/(2\times145)=43/29$

Comment: Where did the +325 go? And the D squared?

Comment: Minimizing $D^2$ is the same as minimizing $D$. 325 simply adds an offset to $D^2$ and hence does not affect the derivative.